# How to add equations on top of arrows?

Tags: align, matrices

I have the following matrix:

```
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
-4&2&-2&10 \\ 1&0&1&-3 \\ 3&-1&1&-8
\end{array}
\right]
\sim
$$
```

I want to have something like this:
[image]

How shall I add equations on top of the `~` and make these align? 
Thanks!

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, simplifying the code; the new version might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the help of `\overset` and a `\parbox`, you can achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength\TextWd
\setlength\TextWd{2.5cm}

\newcommand\Textsim[1]{%
\overset{\parbox[b]{2.5cm}{%
  \centering\scriptsize#1}}{\sim}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
-4&2&-2&10 \\ 
1&0&1&-3 \\ 
3&-1&1&-8
\end{bmatrix}
&\Textsim{$R_{1}\Leftrightarrow R_2$ \\ \mbox{} }
\begin{bmatrix}
-4&2&-2&10 \\ 
1&0&1&-3 \\ 
3&-1&1&-8
\end{bmatrix} \\
&\Textsim{$-2R_{1}+R_2\Rightarrow R_2$ \\ $R_1+ R_3\Rightarrow R_3$ }
\begin{bmatrix}
-4&2&-2&10 \\ 
1&0&1&-3 \\ 
3&-1&1&-8
\end{bmatrix} \\
&\Textsim{$2R_{2}+R_3\Rightarrow R_3$ \\ \mbox{}}
\begin{bmatrix}
-4&2&-2&10 \\ 
1&0&1&-3 \\ 
3&-1&1&-8
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Using the length `\TextWd` you can control the width of the box.

[image]

Notice that `$$...$$` is old TeX syntax which should be replaced with `\[...\]` in LaTeX documents. I also built the matrices using `bmatrix` from `amsmath`.

Comment: For reference: [Why is \\[ … \\] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using stacks.  The `9pt` stackgap is the distance between baselines of the stacked material above the `\sim`, while the `10pt` optional argument to `\stackunder` is the gap between successive matrices.  The `1in` `\makebox` is the width allotted for the center `\sim` stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{L}{9pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\stackunder[10pt]{
\stackunder[10pt]{
\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}
\begin{bmatrix}
-4&2&-2&10 \\ 
1&0&1&-3 \\ 
3&-1&1&-8
\end{bmatrix}
\makebox[1in]{\Longstack{\scriptstyle R_{1}\Leftrightarrow R_2\\\sim}}
\begin{bmatrix}
-4&2&-2&10 \\ 
1&0&1&-3 \\ 
3&-1&1&-8
\end{bmatrix}
}{
\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}
\makebox[1in]{\Longstack{
  \scriptstyle -2R_{1}+R_2\Rightarrow R_2 \\ \scriptstyle R_1+ R_3\Rightarrow R_3\\\sim}}
\begin{bmatrix}
-4&2&-2&10 \\ 
1&0&1&-3 \\ 
3&-1&1&-8
\end{bmatrix}
}}{
\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}
\makebox[1in]{\Longstack{
  \scriptstyle 2R_{2}+R_3\Rightarrow R_3\\\sim}}
\begin{bmatrix}
-4&2&-2&10 \\ 
1&0&1&-3 \\ 
3&-1&1&-8
\end{bmatrix}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]